# Trouble using XYZ Tiles in QGIS 3 on Mac

Tags: qgis-3, data-source

I am trying to load background map from OSM and having problems.  The data source browser->XYZ Tile comes 'pre loaded' with a link for standard OSM and this works fine.  When I try to add a new source (right click -> new connection...) and fill out the dialogue with the Tile url from [OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers) the item appears in the menu but when I click on it I get a legend entry but no layer is displayed.

[image]

I have looked through the message but could not find anything relevant.

I have also tried Thunderforest links with api key but got the same result.

Comment: Is it possibly a projection problem? Can you change your canvas to the spatial reference of the WMS to see if it shows up then.. That's about the limit of my Mac experience, I haven't touched one since they were based on MC68000.

Comment: Good try, but changing the CRS mad no difference.  I have no idea if this is a Mac issue or not I just include that info for completeness.   3.0 has had much less testing on Macs! Currently considering logging this as a bug.

Comment: Hey @RussellFulton, please mark this question as answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause of Problem and Solution**

The problem is subtle. What he had entered was:

***"http://a.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png "***

Notice the extra trailing space after ".png" !

So, the problem is easily rectified as follow:-

(1) In the *Layers* panel, delete the problematic layer.

(2) In the *Browser* panel, edit the connection details , ie remove the trailing space.

(3) Re-Add the selected connection to canvas.

**Misc Information**

In the [link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers) given by the questioner, OpenStreetMap gave the URL for OpenCycleMap as "http://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png".

For QGIS on Windows, User can enter the URL where-is-as-is. For QGIS on MacOS, User must omit the "$", ie "http://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png".

As a recommendation, instead of using "a.tile.opencyclemap.org", the Questioner may wish to use "tile.thunderforest.com" as Host "a" be not be load-balanced.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded adding the Esri tile map as follows:

[image]