# Viewing OSM in QGIS 3.2 vs QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

In QGIS 2.18 I can view OSM using XY tiles no problem. In 3.2 however, copy/pasting the same string in the URL for a new connection doesn't work. The CRS for both is the same. In 3.2 it doesn't matter what I use, quickmapservices or xytiles, I cannot view tiles. Not Bing, Google, OSM, nothing. I must be missing something basic in the differences between QGIS versions but I can't think what it is.

Comment: I had no problem using the Quick Map Services plugin with 3.2.2.  There is a 3.2.3 version available for download.  Sometimes you can fix things by deleting your .qgis2 folder in your user folder and letting QGIS rebuild it.  You can save a copy of the .qgis2 folder to replace the new one in case that doesn't fix things and you have lost some useful customizations.

Comment: @johns QGIS 3 does not use the .qgis2 folder anymore.

Comment: Just to be sure I uninstalled all versions of QGIS and reinstalled 3.2.3 Unfortunately, still cannot get any tiles to display. But thanks to @johns

Comment: What OS are you using? Add some screenshots of the various steps you're taking to add XYZ tiles, and the layer properties and so on. Without more information it's impossible to tell what's going wrong for you.

Comment: If you're using a Mac, check out this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281365/trouble-using-xyz-tiles-in-qgis-3-on-mac

Comment: Windows 10 CRS EPSG:3857

Comment: Windows 10 OS     CRS EPSG:3857  I open a new project, click on QuickMapServices -> OSM ->OSMStandard. It shows up in Layers panel. It doesn't display. When I check on the properties it shows 
Cache stats:  Property Value Hits 0, Misses 0, Errors 803

Comment: Thanks AndreJ for that info for future reference.  Mike, purely by analogy to the most commonly suggested fix for ArcGIS problems you might rename your QGIS folder in your AppData/Roaming folder prior to attempting a reinstall.  I don't know enough about QGIS 3 to know whether that folder is untouched by uninstall/reinstalls like the ArcGIS one but if are willing on its failure to completely remove all QGIS and start afresh, this might be worth a try.  If all your other plugins are working you could just rename the quick_map_services in the plugins folder and try to reinstall the plugin.

Comment: I did a complete clean, first the uninstall of all QGIS versions, then did a registry clean, then searched for all instances of the letters qgis in filenames. Removed all of those files and folders. There were a few in the AppData folder. Then did a clean install of 3.2.3  Rather than risk a typo I copy pasted the pythone code by Klas Karlsson that was online in another post. Sad to say when dragged to the canvas, none of those tile servers produced an image. I double checked the url and they were all identical to that published. Regretfully I'll have to go back to 2.18 Thanks @johns